# How to get xlsx file's border use xlrd/

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I wanna get a xlsx file's border use xlrd, for example:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("./file/test.xls", formatting_info=True)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
cell = Cell(sheet)
nrows = sheet.nrows
ncols = sheet.ncols
row_list = []
for row in range(nrows):
    col_list = []
    for col in range(ncols):
        fmt = book.xf_list[sheet.cell(row, col).xf_index]
        col_list.append(fmt.border)
    row_list.append(col_list)
merged_cells = []
print row_list[5][1].dump()
```

the information in console:

```
bottom_colour_index: 63
bottom_line_style: 2
diag_colour_index: 0
diag_down: 0
diag_line_style: 0
diag_up: 0
left_colour_index: 63
left_line_style: 2
right_colour_index: 8
right_line_style: 2
top_colour_index: 63
top_line_style: 2
None
```

if I open a xlsx file like these codes:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("./file/test.xlsx", formatting_info=False)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
cell = Cell(sheet)
nrows = sheet.nrows
ncols = sheet.ncols
row_list = []
for row in range(nrows):
    col_list = []
    for col in range(ncols):
        fmt = book.xf_list[sheet.cell(row, col).xf_index]
        col_list.append(fmt.border)
    row_list.append(col_list)
merged_cells = []
print row_list[5][1].dump()
```

the information in console like these:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "judge_merged.py", line 68,
>   in 
>       fmt = book.xf_list[sheet.cell(row, col).xf_index] TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType

I don't know how to fix the bug. I need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are passing `formatting_info=False`, `xf_index` for all cells would be `None`.

Open the workbook with `formatting_info=True`.

Comment: When I open the workbook with formatting_info=True,I get a new error,like these:  File "judge_merged.py", line 54, in <module>
    book = xlrd.open_workbook("./file/test.xlsx", formatting_info=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 416, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 748, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    raise NotImplementedError("formatting_info=True not yet implemented")
NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented

Comment: @KarlDoenitz gotcha, then, you would need to switch to openpyxl I bet.